# I want to get the image cordinates in PHP on clicking the submit button, when I try the below code getting error for isset

Tags: php

```
<?Php
    function imagecheck(){
        if(isset($_POST(["x"]) && isset($_POST(["y"])){
            echo "X : ".$_POST["x"]."<br />";
                echo "Y : ".$_POST["y"]."<br />";
        }
        else{
            echo "Click on the image<br />";
        }
    }

?>
```

In the above code, getting error as

> "Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in c:forms.php"

I am a beginner in PHP, kindly help

Answer (score 6):

```
    if(isset($_POST(["x"]) && isset($_POST(["y"])){
                   ^-----^---
```

$_POST is a superglobal **ARRAY**. It is NOT a function.

The code should be

```
if (isset($_POST['x']) && isset($_POST['y'])) {
```

Comment: thanks .. now the error is fixed

Comment: I am getting error for unexpected "{", after changing the code -Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on the line of if

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement should be ...

```
if( isset( $_POST["x"] ) && isset( $_POST["y"] ) )
```

Comment: now I am not getting error. Thanks